# Pandas not listing every single unique value in a column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, emoji

I am trying to list every single unique value in a single column, so I can copy and paste them. But, when I do it, it only seems to list the first 1000 unique values in my column.

When I count the number of unique values in my column, I get 2038:

```
df['Emojis'].nunique()

2038
```

Then, when I use this code to list all the unique values in my column, it only seems to list the first **1000** unique values, in which it is then followed by a `...`

```
df['Emojis'].tolist()
```

```
['',
 '',
 '',
 '',
 '',
 '',
 '☺',
 '',
 '',
 '',
 '',
 '',
 '',
 '',
 '',
 '',
 '',
 '',
 '',
 '',
 '',
 '',
 '',
 '',
 '',
 '',
 '',
 '',
 '',
 '',
 '',
 '',
 '',
 '',
 '',
 '',
 '',
 '',
 '',
 '',
 '',
 '',
 '',
 '',
 '',
 '',
 '',
 '',
 '',
 '',
 '',
 '',
 '',
 '',
 '❤',
 '',
 '❤',
 '',
 '',
 '',
 '',
 '',
 '',
 '',
 '',
 '',
 '',
 '❤',
 '',
 '',
 '',
 '',
 '',
 '',
 '',
 '',
 '✨',
 '',
 '',
 '',
 '',
 '',
 '',
 '',
 '',
 '',
 '',
 '',
 '',
 '',
 '',
 '❤',
 '',
 '',
 '',
 '',
 '❤',
 '',
 '',
 '',
 '✨',
 '',
 '',
 '',
 '♥',
 '',
 '',
 '',
 '',
 '',
 '',
 '',
 '',
 '',
 '',
 '',
 '',
 '',
 '',
 '',
 '♥',
 '',
 '❤',
 '',
 '',
 '',
 '',
 '',
 '',
 '',
 '',
 '',
 '',
 '❤',
 '❤',
 '',
 '',
 '',
 '',
 '',
 '',
 '',
 '',
 '☺',
 '',
 '',
 '',
 '',
 '',
 '',
 '',
 '',
 '',
 '',
 '',
 '',
 '',
 '',
 '',
 '',
 '',
 '',
 '❤',
 '',
 '',
 '',
 '',
 '',
 '',
 '',
 '',
 '',
 '',
 '',
 '',
 '',
 '',
 '',
 '❤',
 '',
 '',
 '',
 '',
 '',
 '',
 '',
 '',
 '',
 '',
 '',
 '♥',
 '',
 '',
 '',
 '',
 '',
 '',
 '',
 '✨',
 '',
 '',
 '',
 '',
 '',
 '',
 '',
 '',
 '',
 '',
 '',
 '',
 '',
 '',
 '',
 '',
 '❤',
 '',
 '',
 '',
 '',
 '',
 '',
 '',
 '',
 '',
 '☀',
 '',
 '',
 '',
 '',
 '❤',
 '',
 '',
 '',
 '',
 '',
 '',
 '',
 '❤',
 '',
 '',
 '',
 '♥',
 '',
 '',
 '',
 '',
 '',
 '',
 '',
 '',
 '',
 '',
 '',
 '❤',
 '',
 '',
 '',
 '',
 '',
 '❤',
 '',
 '',
 '',
 '',
 '',
 '',
 '',
 '',
 '',
 '',
 '',
 '',
 '',
 '',
 '',
 '❤',
 '',
 '',
 '',
 '',
 '☕',
 '',
 '',
 '',
 '',
 '',
 '❤',
 '',
 '',
 '',
 '',
 '',
 '',
 '⚡',
 '',
 '',
 '',
 '☺',
 '',
 '',
 '',
 '',
 '✨',
 '',
 '',
 '',
 '',
 '',
 '',
 '',
 '',
 '',
 '',
 '',
 '',
 '',
 '',
 '',
 '',
 '',
 '',
 '',
 '',
 '',
 '',
 '❤',
 '',
 '',
 '',
 '',
 '',
 '',
 '',
 '',
 '',
 '',
 '',
 '',
 '',
 '',
 '',
 '',
 '',
 '',
 '',
 '',
 '',
 '',
 '',
 '',
 '',
 '',
 '',
 '',
 '',
 '',
 '',
 '',
 '',
 '',
 '',
 '',
 '',
 '',
 '',
 '',
 '',
 '',
 '',
 '',
 '',
 '',
 '',
 '☺',
 '',
 '♥',
 '',
 '❤',
 '',
 '',
 '',
 '',
 '®',
 '',
 '',
 '',
 '',
 '',
 '',
 '',
 '',
 '☀',
 '❤',
 '',
 '',
 '',
 '',
 '',
 '✨',
 '',
 '',
 '',
 '',
 '',
 '',
 '☺',
 '',
 '',
 '',
 '',
 '',
 '❤',
 '',
 '',
 '',
 '',
 '',
 '',
 '',
 '',
 '',
 '',
 '',
 '',
 '',
 '',
 '',
 '',
 '',
 '',
 '',
 '',
 '',
 '',
 '',
 '',
 '',
 '',
 '',
 '',
 '',
 '',
 '',
 '',
 '',
 '',
 '',
 '',
 '',
 '',
 '',
 '',
 '',
 '',
 '',
 '',
 '',
 '',
 '✨',
 '',
 '',
 '',
 '',
 '',
 '',
 '',
 '',
 '',
 '❤',
 '',
 '',
 '',
 '',
 '',
 '',
 '',
 '',
 '',
 '',
 '',
 '❤',
 '',
 '♥',
 '',
 '',
 '',
 '',
 '',
 '',
 '',
 '',
 '',
 '',
 '',
 '',
 '',
 '',
 '',
 '',
 '',
 '',
 '',
 '',
 '',
 '',
 '',
 '',
 '',
 '',
 '',
 '',
 '',
 '',
 '',
 '',
 '',
 '',
 '',
 '',
 '',
 '',
 '',
 '',
 '',
 '',
 '',
 '',
 '',
 '',
 '',
 '',
 '',
 '⚡',
 '',
 '',
 '',
 '',
 '',
 '',
 '',
 '',
 '',
 '',
 '',
 '',
 '',
 '',
 '❤',
 '',
 '',
 '',
 '',
 '',
 '✨',
 '',
 '',
 '',
 '',
 '❤',
 '',
 '',
 '',
 '',
 '',
 '',
 '',
 '',
 '',
 '✨',
 '',
 '❤',
 '',
 '',
 '',
 '',
 '',
 '',
 '',
 '',
 '',
 '',
 '',
 '',
 '',
 '',
 '',
 '',
 '',
 '',
 '',
 '',
 '✨',
 '',
 '',
 '',
 '',
 '',
 '',
 '',
 '',
 '',
 '',
 '',
 '❤',
 '',
 '',
 '',
 '',
 '',
 '',
 '',
 '',
 '',
 '',
 '',
 '',
 '',
 '',
 '',
 '',
 '',
 '❤',
 '',
 '',
 '',
 '',
 '',
 '☺',
 '',
 '',
 '',
 '',
 '',
 '✨',
 '',
 '',
 '',
 '',
 '',
 '',
 '',
 '',
 '☕',
 '',
 '',
 '',
 '',
 '',
 '',
 '',
 '',
 '',
 '',
 '',
 '❤',
 '',
 '',
 '',
 '',
 '',
 '',
 '',
 '❤',
 '',
 '',
 '',
 '',
 '',
 '',
 '',
 '',
 '',
 '',
 '❤',
 '',
 '',
 '',
 '☕',
 '',
 '',
 '',
 '',
 '',
 '❤',
 '',
 '',
 '',
 '',
 '',
 '',
 '',
 '',
 '',
 '',
 '',
 '',
 '❤',
 '',
 '',
 '',
 '',
 '',
 '',
 '',
 '',
 '',
 '',
 '',
 '',
 '',
 '',
 '',
 '',
 '',
 '',
 '',
 '',
 '',
 '',
 '',
 '',
 '',
 '',
 '',
 '',
 '',
 '',
 '',
 '',
 '',
 '',
 '',
 '',
 '',
 '',
 '',
 '☔',
 '',
 '',
 '',
 '',
 '',
 '',
 '',
 '❤',
 '',
 '',
 '',
 '',
 '',
 '',
 '',
 '',
 '',
 '',
 '',
 '',
 '',
 '',
 '',
 '',
 '',
 '',
 '',
 '',
 '',
 '',
 '',
 '❤',
 '',
 '',
 '',
 '',
 '',
 '',
 '',
 '',
 '',
 '',
 '',
 '',
 '',
 '',
 '',
 '',
 '',
 '',
 '',
 '',
 '❤',
 '',
 '',
 '',
 '',
 '',
 '',
 '',
 '',
 '',
 '',
 '',
 '',
 '',
 '',
 '❤',
 '',
 '',
 '',
 '',
 '❤',
 '',
 '',
 '',
 '❤',
 '',
 '',
 '',
 '',
 '',
 '',
 '',
 '',
 '',
 '',
 '☺',
 '',
 '',
 '',
 '',
 '',
 '',
 '',
 '',
 '',
 '',
 '☀',
 '',
 '',
 '',
 '',
 '',
 '',
 '❤',
 '',
 '',
 '',
 '',
 '',
 '',
 '',
 '',
 '',
 '',
 '❤',
 '',
 '☔',
 '',
 '',
 '',
 '',
 '',
 '',
 '',
 '',
 '',
 '',
 '',
 '',
 '',
 '',
 '',
 '',
 '',
 '',
 '',
 '',
 '',
 '',
 '',
 '',
 '',
 '',
 '',
 '',
 '',
 '',
 '',
 '',
 '',
 '',
 '',
 '',
 '',
 '',
 '',
 '',
 '❤',
 '',
 '',
 '',
 '',
 '',
 '',
 '',
 '',
 '',
 '',
 '',
 '',
 '❤',
 '',
 '',
 '',
 '❤',
 '',
 '',
 '',
 '',
 '',
 '',
 '',
 '',
 '',
 '',
 '',
 '',
 '',
 '',
 '',
 '',
 '',
 '',
 '',
 '',
 '',
 '',
 '❤',
 '',
 '',
 '',
 '',
 '',
 '',
 '',
 '',
 '',
 '',
 '',
 '❤',
 '',
 '',
 '',
 '',
 '❤',
 '',
 '',
 '',
 '',
 '',
 '',
 '',
 '',
 '',
 '',
 '',
 '',
 '',
 '',
 '',
 '',
 '',
 '',
 '',
 '',
 '✊',
 '',
 '',
 '',
 '',
 '',
 '',
 '',
 '',
 '',
 '',
 '',
 '',
 '',
 '',
 '',
 '',
 '',
 '',
 '',
 '',
 '',
 '',
 '✌',
 '',
 ...]
```

I am unsure why it does not list all 2038 unique values, which I need.

And...apologies for showing the full output, but I feel it is necessary to show the output for this issues I am having.

Therefore, is there a way to list all 2038 unique values in my column, or extract them all?

Thanks.

Comment: `df['Emojis'].unique()`?

Comment: Hi, I tried that, and it lists 5 emojis followed by the ```...```

Comment: check the output `df['Emojis'].unique().size` or `len(df['Emojis'].unique())`....`df['Emojis'].tolist()` is converting the Series to list but `df['Emojis'].unique()` giving you the list of unique elements of 'Emoji' column

Comment: are you trying to print them in your terminal? by default panda only prints a sample not the whole df

Comment: @AnuragDabas I did that, and there are 2038 unique emojis.

Comment: @ChristopherHolder Yes, I am trying to print them in my terminal. I basically want all 2038 unique emojis and copy them with the apostrophe and comma for each emoji. For example, like this: '', '', '', ''. But I want to copy all 2038 in that format - if that makese sense?

Comment: Did you try out my solution? It should work, not the most efficient but it should fix your issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create a second data frame where you have removed all duplicate function.
For example:

```
df_unique = df.drop_duplicates()

for i in df_unique.index:
   print(df_unique['Emojis'][i])
```

Here is the documentation:
[Pandas remove Duplicates](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.drop_duplicates.html)

Comment: I just tried this, and I get the following error: ```KeyError: 0```

Comment: Does my Emojis column need to be added somewhere in your solution?

Comment: Yes, you are correct. Sorry forgot to add the column key ['Emojis'] should work now.

Comment: btw I think your issue was with printing now with extracting unique values. Take at look at this link for next time https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/options.html

Comment: Hi, that has worked for me - thank you very much. I will take a look at that link - thanks again. Also, is there any way to add ```'  ',``` for each emoji?

Comment: what do you mean?